# hands position for Resharper hot keys combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, hotkeys

I'd like to start using ReSharper keyboard shortcuts but not sure how properly position my hands on a keyboard and which fingers to use for hot keys combinations as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> etc.

I'm used to having my fingers on the home row all the time but with the hotkeys should I move a hand down the home row for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or up the row for function keys as <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> or continue to keep it there?

In either case what fingers are the most convenient for those kinds of key combinations?

Answer (score 2):

Keep your fingers on the home row, and then do whatever is comfortable to hit the key combinations. Then return to the home row when you're done hitting the shortcut.

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, I use my pinky on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, ring on <kbd>Shift</kbd>, thumb on <kbd>Alt</kbd> and middle on <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: What's the advantage of hitting left Shift with the left hand ring finger versus using your right hand pinkie to hit a right Shift key?

Comment: I can issue the entire `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+A` command with my left hand, leaving my right hand on the home row. Do whatever is comfortable.:)